# When is main.min,js file created in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, visual-studio, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use `Visual Studio 2015` along with `Angular`, `bootstrap` and `jquery` in my clients `MVC` and `Web API` based applications.

I noticed that the minified file is created named main.min.js. This file contains most of my javascript in minified version.

Could anyone please know which application is responsible to create this file and when exactly is the create/update triggered for the file?

Comment: This is really just a visual studio question. From a google search, there is a plugin for visual studio called minify that will minify your code on publish. Check if that is installed. I've never used visual studio before

Comment: @Ronnie - Thanks for your reply. No i have not installed any Visual Studio plugin. It is just the bare-bone installation.

Comment: Perhaps it is web api doing it then